# How to change the value of a variable inside a Javascript code with a form

Tags: javascript, forms

I just started learning coding (two days ago) for a school projet, which might be too ambitious for my current skills. I'm trying to create a random graph with a given number of nodes and links, and a given charge nodes. I've used an open source code for random graph generator, but i can't find a way to modify the number of nodes, links and charge with an HTML form. Here is the code which does not work. I would be very glad if someone could help me with this issue. 
(Please be tolerant with my syntax, I'm a beginner...)

```js
var width = 1000,
  height = 1000;

var n = 20, // number of nodes
  m = 100, // number of links
  charge = -10000;

function changevalue() {
  var n = getElementById("numberofnodes").value;
  var m = getElementById("numberoflinks").value;
  var charge = getElementById("chargenumber").value;
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .on("mousedown", create);

create();

function create() {
  svg.selectAll(".link, .node").remove();
  randomGraph(n, m, charge);
}

function randomGraph(n, m, charge) { //creates a random graph on n nodes and m links
  var nodes = d3.range(n).map(Object),
    list = randomChoose(unorderedPairs(d3.range(n)), m),
    links = list.map(function(a) {
      return {
        source: a[0],
        target: a[1]
      }
    });

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .charge(charge)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

  var svgLinks = svg.selectAll(".link").data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

  var svgNodes = svg.selectAll(".node").data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 3)
    .style("fill", "white");

  svgLinks.transition().duration(800)
    .style("stroke-width", 3);

  function tick() {
    svgNodes
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y
      });

    svgLinks
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y
      });
  }
}

function randomChoose(s, k) { // returns a random k element subset of s
  var a = [],
    i = -1,
    j;
  while (++i < k) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length);
    a.push(s.splice(j, 1)[0]);
  };
  return a;
}

function unorderedPairs(s) { // returns the list of all unordered pairs from s
  var i = -1,
    a = [],
    j;
  while (++i < s.length) {
    j = i;
    while (++j < s.length) a.push([s[i], s[j]])
  };
  return a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Random Graph</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .link {
      stroke: black;
    }
    
    .node {
      stroke: green;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Voici un graphe aléatoire</h1>
  <input id="numberofnodes" type="number" />
  <input id="numberoflinks" type="number" />
  <input id="chargenumber" type="number" />
  <button type="button" onclick="changevalue()">OK</button>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `changeValue` is assigning to local variables because of the `var` keywords, not the global variables.

Comment: Just get rid of `var` in that function

Comment: you have to put the inputs into a <form>

Comment: i made all the modifications that you suggested but it still doesn't work...